# Size Class compact height doesn't work properly with UIStackView's axis and real device

Tags: ios, xcode, size-classes

This is how it looks like in my storyboard and Preview:

[image]

And this is what I set up in storyboard for that `UIStackView`:

[image]

But everything changes when I run this on real device:

[image]

Why it happens like that?

Please note that I have here two `UIStackViews`: icon with labels box, two buttons. The second one works correctly, but not the first one. Why? it is done exactly the same way. Two direct subviews of `UIStackView`

**EDIT**

I realised that problem arise **ONLY** with `UIImageView` as direct subview of `UIStackView`.

Comment: Looks like you having problem with the constraints.

Comment: Could you suggest what may be wrong?

Comment: it looks like the wrong size class's layout is being applied. This can happen if the view is layed out offscreen before being presented. It will be Any*Any because the view has no way of knowing which size class to load.

Comment: Do not understand you. Where the view is out of screen?

Comment: In the time between creating the view controller and presenting it. If anything tries to access the view controllers view it will be loaded and laid out but without the size classes.

Comment: Ok, but here there is no view being accessed before it is presented. Everything is set in storyboard.

Comment: @Vaionixx if there was a problem with constraints, then it wouldn't  look good in preview.

Comment: I suppose this is a BUG while runtime.

Comment: I have created a project and rebuilt your stackview from scratch with an image view and two labels. However, I wasn't able to reproduce your issue. It renders correctly when rotating the screen both on my real device and in Simulator. I'd recommend you to do the same in order to isolate the underlying issue: Create a new project and only add a stackview to the empty storyboard with the minimum number of constraints needed.

Comment: Could you share your example project with me? bartekss2@icloud.com

Comment: Have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Just tap the "+" button disribution section and choose Any x Compact height and fill equally. I hope this works well.

Comment: I did like you said, but it still doesnt work:( any other ideas? Any questions?

Comment: Is there a way to force the view to layout it once again when trait collection did change?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk Well, I don't think there is way to force it. Because, when layout has changed horizontally or vertically iOS system has to calculate all of the traits to fit layout properly. Maybe you can do a little hack for this in code but I'm not completely sure. Have a look at this doc https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitenvironment